# Is there a good way to issue unique constraints in hibernate / JPA in annotations or other?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

We need a postgres constraint like so

`create unique index on customer_original_address ( onbehalfofclientid, coalesce(addr1, ''), coalesce(addr2, ''), city, state, zipcode);`

Ideally, we could use something like this but this appears to only take column names..

```
@Table(name="CUSTOMER_ORIGINAL_ADDRESS",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name="uniqueAddr", columnNames = 
             {"onBehalfOfClientId", "addr1", "addr2", "city", "state", "zipCode"})
)
```

Is there another way to include something that runs on updating database and such?  If not, is there a way to grab the jdbc connection from hibernate and then query for the constraint's existence and if not there, create it ourselves?

Comment: Consider not letting Hibernate automatically generate or update your schema, and instead use migration tools like Liquibase or Flyway. Letting Hibernate generate the schema is an option that is not advisable for use on production systems.